# No logro comprender aplicando la estructura asociativa php

Tags: php, foreach

Por un determinado peaje pasan en un día 2500 vehículos del tipo motos, autos, camionetas y pesados. Desarrolle una página `peaje.php` que realice la simulación del peaje y recaudación del día. Genere aleatoriamente la cantidad de vehículos según el tipo, y su correspondiente recaudación. También debe informase el total recaudado en el día. Se sabe que las motos pagan $35, los autos $60, las camionetas $85 y los pesados $120 en dicho peaje.

Utilice un arreglo como el siguiente, para obtener aleatoriamente un tipo
de vehículo:

```
$tarifa = array('motos'=>35,'autos'=>60,'camionetas'=>85,'pesados'=>120);
```

Muestre toda la información de la siguiente forma: Ejemplo

```
Cantidad de motos 629 y recaudación $ 21910
Cantidad de autos 640 y recaudación $ 38400
Cantidad de camioneta 596 y recaudación $ 50660
Cantidad de pesados 638 y recaudación $ 76560

Total de vehiculos : 2500
Recaudación del día: $187530
```

Usar contadores y acumuladores aplicando forech.

Así lo voy desarrollando pero no entiendo su resolución

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que voy haciendo es:

```
<?php
// --- Constantes -----
define ('AUTOSDIARIOS', 2500);
// --- Variables ------
$contMotos = 0;
$contAutos = 0;
$contCamionetas = 0;
$contPesados = 0;
 
// --- Arreglo ------
$tarifas = array(
    'motos'=>35,'autos'=>60,'camionetas'=>85,'pesados'=>120
);

foreach ($tarifa as $clave => $valor) {
    switch ($clave) {
        case 'motos':
            break;
        case 'autos':
            break;
        case 'camionetas':
            break;
        case 'pesados':
            break;
        default:
            echo '<p>'.'Error tipo tipo de vehiculo.'.'</p>';
            break;
    }//fin el segun
}// fin del foreach
echo '<hr>';
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113274/discussion-on-question-by-augusto-no-logro-comprender-aplicando-la-estructura-as).